# OpenCV read image and manage their pixel with integer values (like matlab)

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

In matlab when I use imread function the pixel values of an image are stored in a 3D matrix (of uint8). The values of the matrix are between 0 and 255. But in OpenCV the imread function stores the values in a `cv::Mat`. When I try to see the values of the pixels I see float values and when I try to convert to integer I have big values.

How can I see the `cv::Mat` components (RGB) with values between 0 and 255 like in Matlab?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

cv::Mat can be used with any type of pixel, if you use imread it will create a cv::Mat of the correct type.

Floating point images are unusual - are you sure the source data is floating point or are you just printing the values wrong?

You can convert a floating point image into 8bit ( CV8UC3) with cvtcolor()

Comment: I'd suspect that he is printing the values wrong. @msdark: to access the blue component of the pixel at row `y` and column `x`, you want to use something like `unsigned char b = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[0]` (images are loaded in BGR order in opencv).

Comment: for example i have a grayscale image and i try with Vec3b, Vec2i and Vec2f and .. with Vec3b i see values like (v,z) .. for Vec2i (2020038511,1632856665) and for Vec2f the float version of Vec2i.

Answer (score 1):

```
int red = (int)((uchar*)pImg->imageData)[y*((int)pImg->widthStep)+x*3+C];
```

Those are for `IplImage`. Don't know if works for Mat. `C=(0 or 1 or 2)` is for color channel.

Answer (score 0):

I normally store images in type `IplImage*` rather than `cv::Mat`. If I say `IplImage* frame = (get image somehow...)`, then I can say `frame->imageData` to see the values you are interested in. The values are arranged for an RGB image in a single array `[r1, b1, g1, r2, b2, g2, r3, b3, g3, ..., r(height*width), b(height*width), g(height*width)]`, and I believe they are arranged row-wise.

Comment: cv::Mat is the same format as iplimage, the order of pixel color isn't defied - it depends on the source they were read from. Many cameras will generate BGR, especially on windows

Answer (score 0):

An example of the results

i have this:

```
Canny(test,edges,0.9*av[0],2*av[0],3,true);
    for(int i=0;i<edges.rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<edges.cols;j++){
            cv::Vec2w& elem = edges.at<cv::Vec2w>(i,j);
            std::cout << elem[0] << " , "<<elem[1] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

the edges (cv::Mat) variable storage the result of cv::Canny function (a binary image) .. when i try to see the values of pixels using cv::Vec2w i have this for result:
6408 , 2058
1817 , 7433
1540 , 282
5386 , 1024
15 , 4867
768 , 275
1285 , 512
2 , 0
0 , 0
1 , 256
with cv::Vec2

0 , 0
0 , 0
0 , 0
0 , 0
0 , -256
255 , -256
0 , 0
0 , 0

with cv::Vec2i

0 , 0
0 , 0
-16777216 , -16776961
0 , 0
0 , -256
-1 , 65535
0 , -16777216
65535 , 0
0 , 0

and so on...

But for example if i write this image (imwrite("image.pgm",edges) ) and then reading with [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) (the image es a single channel binary image) i have for the result an matrix (nx1) with values between 0 and 255 .. i know .. the format of both libraries is different, but .. i supose: binary image always have values 0 and 255 in one channel ....

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `edges.at<cv::Vec2b>(i,j)`, not cv::Vec2w or cv::Vec2i.